# Adjust the height of ggplot bar graph in a tabpabel in Shiny Dashboard

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shinydashboard, r-plotly

I'm rendering a barplot using `plotly` and `ggplot` in a `tabPanel` in shiny Dashboard. Below is my code on the `tabPanel` in the UI section.

```
tabBox(width =12, id = "plot4", height = "320px", selected = "FarmInputs",
   tabPanel("FarmInputs", plotlyOutput("inputsPlot", height = "auto"))
   )
```

I've also tried this in the tabPanel

```
tabPanel("FarmInputs", plotlyOutput("inputsPlot"),height = "320px")
```

in the  server function

```
renderPlotly({
ggplot(aes(var,value))+geom_bar(stat="Identity")+coord_flip()+theme_gdocs()
})
```

The plot renders outside the desired height of the tabPanel, as seen in the screenshot. How do I control the height of the plot so that it renders exaclty in the tabPanel?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the height in the `renderPlot` function. This is the code:
`renderPlot(expr, width = "auto", height = "auto")`